# Graphviz - how to display the edge count for concentrated edges?

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I have a directed graph that concentrates overlapping edges on to one edge. A sample .dot file is given below:

```
strict digraph Test {
concentrate=true
A -> B;
A -> B;
A -> B;
}
```

I would like to display the number of overlapping edges as the edge label. This sounds pretty trivial, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Is this possible? If possible how do I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Only way is to do some post-processing yourself on the .gv file before feeding it to dot.  You'd have to modify the output to explicitly include the text you want, such as:

```
strict digraph Test
{
    concentrate=true
    A -> B [label="3 connections between A and B"];
}
```